# pandas combine rows with overlapping values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like use pandas to group overlapping intervals within the same block number.
This is the input df:

```
block   start   end
1   100 105
1   105 200
1   195 205
2   1   10
2   10  25
2   15  20
2   18  30
2   30  40
```

the expected output is

```
block   start   end
1   100 105
1   105 205
2   1   10
2   10  30
2   30  40
```

Answer (score 4):

first create a `grp`, which you then use in your `groupby`:

```
grp = (df.groupby('block').apply(lambda x: (x['start'].ge(x['end'].shift())
                                            .cumsum())).reset_index(drop=True))
df.groupby(['block', grp], as_index=False).agg({'start': 'min', 'end' : 'max'})
Out[1]: 
   block  start  end
0      1    100  105
1      1    105  205
2      2      1   10
3      2     10   30
4      2     30   40
```

For creation of `grp`:

1. You know what you want to groupby -- `block`
2. The hard part is how you can possibly do some sort of function after gouping by `block`
3. You can achieve this by `lambda x` on the `dataframe` where `x` is the dataframe and you can use multiple columns. If you call just a column after the `groupby` syntax, then you cannot compare multiple columns in a function.
4. The `lambda x:` basically looks at any given `start` row per group and compares to the previous `end` row with `.ge` (greater than or equal) and `.shift()`. That returns `True` or `False` row-by-row in a multi-index series, so you are ready to take the `cumsum()` to get the group numbers per block and `.reset_index()` so that the index is the same as the dataframe and can be used in a `.groupby()`
5. So, use this series `grp` as another series to include in a `groupby` to transform your dataframe as required with `agg`

Answer (score 0):

This solution works.

The key is to identify which records need to be joined, (those where the diff in end time between it and the previous record is greater than the diff between it's own start and end time), then join them using groupby.

Repeat until all overlapping records have been merged.

```py
df_txt = """
bl  st  end
1   100 105
1   105 200
1   195 205
2   1   10
2   10  25
2   15  20
2   18  30
2   30  40"""

df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(df_txt)).rename(columns={'bl':'block','st':'start'})

df['next_end_diff'] = df.groupby('block')['end'].diff()
df['st_to_st_diff'] = df.groupby('block')['start'].diff()
df['st_to_end_diff'] = df['end']-df['start']
df_mask = df['next_end_diff']<df['st_to_end_diff']
df.loc[df_mask,'start'] = df.loc[df_mask,'start'] - df.loc[df_mask,'st_to_st_diff']
df = df.groupby(['block','start'])['end'].max().reset_index()
while sum(df_mask)>0:
    df['next_end_diff'] = df.groupby('block')['end'].diff()
    df['st_to_st_diff'] = df.groupby('block')['start'].diff()
    df['st_to_end_diff'] = df['end']-df['start']
    df_mask = df['next_end_diff']<df['st_to_end_diff']
    df.loc[df_mask,'start'] = df.loc[df_mask,'start'] - df.loc[df_mask,'st_to_st_diff']
    df = df.groupby(['block','start'])['end'].max().reset_index()
```